# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a project in `CodeIgniter` and trying to create a `login` functionality.

I just created a session on logging and passed the logged in user's id to the dashboard, but it showing me an error. Here is my code.

My controller - login controller ---------

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Auth_model','',true);
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login/index');
    }

    public function verifyUser(){
        $userArray = array(
            "email"=>$this->input->post("email"),
            "password"=>$this->input->post("password"),
        );   
        $loggedUserData = $this->Auth_model->checkUser($userArray);  
        var_dump($loggedUserData);
        if(count($loggedUserData)>0){
            // this is where we creating session
           $this->session->set_userdata('loggedUserData',$loggedUserData);
           //redirect('dashboard/index');       
        }else{
           redirect('login');        
        }
    }
    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

My Model - Auth_model ---------

```
class Auth_model extends CI_model{  
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function checkUser($userArray){
        $loggedUserData = $this->db->select('id')
             ->where('email',$userArray["email"])
             ->where('password',$userArray["password"])
             ->get('users');
        return $loggedUserData->row();
        // here we are going to check the user with db
    }
}
```

My view - dashboard------------

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $currentUserData = $this->session->userdata();
        if(!isset($currentUserData["loggedUserData"])){
            redirect('/login/');
        }
    }
    public function index(){
        //$this->load->view('dashboard/index');
        echo $this->session->userdata['loggedUserData']['id'];
    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+use+object+of+type+stdClass+as+array

Comment: What`s the error?

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: In which part of the code?

Comment: Is it this>  echo $this->session->userdata['loggedUserData']['id'];

Comment: yeap , i want to get the id of logged user , how can i do it

Comment: try this> echo $this->session->userdata('loggedUserData')->id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is happening because of this call in the model.

```
return $loggedUserData->row();
```

The method `row()` returns and object, but you want an array. Change the above to

```
return $loggedUserData->row_array();
```

and the error will go away. Not to say everything will work.

Comment: when i change this it worked, thank you for all who try to help me

Comment: $loggedUserData = $this->Auth_model->checkUser($userArray);

Comment: $loggedUserData = json_decode(json_encode($loggedUserData), True);

Comment: @SL cLaY, Your last line is weird. Why encode then decode? Its an array, you don't have to do that.

Comment: @Alex its not a array i think its object, i want convert it into array,

Comment: Many things work in php, it's a very forgiving language. It doesn't meant what you are doing is right. If you truly followed this answer it means you are already getting an array so you don't have to do anything else to it. Not to mention what your last line does is turn the array into an object with encode and then back into an array with decode, it doesn't change the data at all!